# How to "Promise" (or callback) this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have 2 lists in my Sharepoint : speeches and schools.
In my speeches form, I have a school field. I want to autocomplete this field with values (name, adress, city) from schools list.
Here's my code :

```
$(School_fieldID).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term.replace(/ /g, "*\",\"*");
        var searchUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='and(\"*" + term + "*\",path:\"" + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Schools\")'&enablefql=true";
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

        executor.executeAsync({
            url: searchUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
                var results = jsonObject.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
                var schoolList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Schools');

                response($.map(results, function (result) {
                    school = schoolList.getItemById(result.Cells.results[6].Value.split('=').pop());
                    clientContext.load(school, 'Title', 'Adress', 'City');
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (schoolName, schoolAdress, schoolCity) {
                        schoolName = school.get_item('Title');
                        schoolAdress = school.get_item('Adress');
                        schoolCity = school.get_item('City');
                    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                        alert('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
                    }));
                    return {
                        label: schoolName + " (" + schoolAdress + " " + /*schoolCity + */ ")",
                        value: schoolName
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I test this code, schoolName, schoolAdress et schoolCity are undefined because of asynchronous function `executeQueryAsync`.
So I think solution is in Promise or Callback, but I tried different solutions for a week, without success :-(
Please note I read carefully this post [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but can't find a good solution anyway...
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance,
Florent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have to pass an array of objects to the response callback function and each one of the result is calling the async function `clientContext.executeQueryAsync` we can turn each one of them into a promise and pass them to Promise.all() which will wait for all of them to be resolved and returned them.
When they are all resolved, the objects will be inside the `schoolObjectArray` which then you can pass to the response function.
Is should work.

```
$(School_fieldID).autocomplete({
minLength: 2,
source: function (request, response) {
    var term = request.term.replace(/ /g, "*\",\"*");
    var searchUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='and(\"*" + term + "*\",path:\"" + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Schools\")'&enablefql=true";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    executor.executeAsync({
        url: searchUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
            var results = jsonObject.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var schoolList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Schools');

            Promise.all($.map(results, function (result) {
                school = schoolList.getItemById(result.Cells.results[6].Value.split('=').pop());
                clientContext.load(school, 'Title', 'Adress', 'City');
                return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (schoolName, schoolAdress, schoolCity) {
                    schoolName = school.get_item('Title');
                    schoolAdress = school.get_item('Adress');
                    schoolCity = school.get_item('City');
                    resolve({
                            label: schoolName + " (" + schoolAdress + " " + /*schoolCity + */ ")",
                            value: schoolName
                        });
                    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                        reject('Error occured: ' + args.get_message());
                    }));
                })
            }))
            .then(function(schoolObjectArray){
                response(schoolObjectArray)
            })
            .catch(console.error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)
I tried this code but it return only one value. Do you know why ? I don't understand...

Comment: it should return the array with the values in it, being in the $map function. I dont think it will change but you could turn snippet:  `$.map(results,` into `results.map(`. With "only one value" you mean it returns an array with one value or only an object?